# getting pcl_visualization

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

can anyone help me on getting the perception_pcl_addons stack to my hard disk?

i know i'm supposed to do some svn stuff but i cant figure out the exact syntax that i need to issue.

many tanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10425/getting-pcl_visualization/) by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/trunk perception_pcl_addons`

If you are not installing from source, use:
`sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-perception-pcl-addons`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on 2011-06-28**:
got it, i used the apt-get. just needed the syntax! thanks!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-28**:
The svn checkouts are local, not system-wide (i.e. in /opt/...)

**Comment by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on 2011-06-28**:
thanks, i did that, but i still cant see the actual folder for that stack in my /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks folder...any ideas?